# MongoDb limit to N results, but count all matching documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to make search query that `limit` to `N` results but i want to show the user how many `documents` matched the search criteria.

My query is:

```
Project.find({query}, {
    selection
    }).limit(N).sort(-updated).exec(function(err,docs) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        if(docs) {
            res.send(docs);
        }
    })
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you not make another query that will do 'count' all results?

Comment: Which version of `mongoDB` are you using?

Comment: Can't i do that with only single query?

Comment: and i"m using mongo 3.0.7

Answer (score 1):

In mongo console its possible using a single query.

```
> var docs = db.collection.find(query).skip(10).limit(10)
> docs.count() 
1289
> docs.length() 
10
```

There must a similar way to achieve this in node driver

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted, Thanks